# Angular 5 - Use variable from view-model in HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, typescript, ecmascript-6, angular5

I have a variable in my view-model with its setter and getter called: **orderStatusColor**.

This is a string as follows: "*color: red*" or "*color: green*".

How can I use this as a style in my HTML? I have tried using ngStyle but I get an error which says

"*DevicesStatusComponent.html:12 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object 'color: red'*"

**controller.ts**

```
private orderStatusColorCode(code: string){

    const codeRed = this.orderInProgressCmsModel.orderStatusColorRed.split(",");

    if(codeRed.some(s => s.includes(code))){
      this.orderStatusColor = "color: red";
    }
    return this.orderStatusColor;
}

orderViewModel.devices =
          new DevicesStatusViewModel(
            this.orderStatusColor
          );
```

**view-model.ts**

```
interface DevicesStatusViewModelI {
  orderStatusColor: string;
}

export class DevicesStatusViewModel implements DevicesStatusViewModelI {
  private _orderStatusColor = '';

  get orderStatusColor(): string { return this._orderStatusColor; }

  set orderStatusColor(orderStatusColor: string) {
    this._orderStatusColor = (orderStatusColor != null) ? orderStatusColor : "";
  }

  constructor(orderStatusColor?: string) {
    this.orderStatusColor = orderStatusColor;
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ng-container>
    <p ngStyle="{{devicesStatusViewModel.orderStatusColor}}">Test</p>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: If you could have searched for "Cannot find a differ supporting object", you would have got your answer

Comment: I did search and did see that I needed to return an object instead of string but I wanted to know if there was a way possible to just return the string and work with the string itself :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following

```
if(codeRed.some(s => s.includes(code))){
  this.orderStatusColor = '{"color": "red"}';
}
```

Parse the JSON string to JSON object (as ngStyle expects an object) in component like below

```
this.orderStatusColor = JSON.parse('{"color": "red"}');
```

Now you can use it in template html like

```
<div [ngStyle]="orderStatusColor">
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems, you have passed a string in the variable `devicesStatusViewModel.orderStatusColor`, instead it should be an object. Just like below

**component.ts**

```
public style = {color:'blue'};
```

**component.html**

```
<h1 [ngStyle]="style">This is header in blue</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

it would seem you haven't been using the ngstyle directive well.
You should put it between [] as shown on the official website [LINK](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle)